# background color rotate css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to rotate background like below image but did not get any luck. Here is css code and html Markup. also if we do similar thing with svg, is it better approach?

```css
.diagonal-shadow::before, .diagonal-shadow::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  pointer-events: none;
}
.diagonal-shadow::before, .diagonal-shadow::after {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35%;
  background: inherit;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.diagonal-shadow::before {
  height: 14%;
  background: #333 !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
  transform: rotate(6deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 3% 0;
  transform-origin: 70% 0;
}
.col{
  background:#f6f6f6;
  padding: 40px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="diagonal-shadow">
<div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum a viverra quam. Vestibulum maximus consequat porta. Duis aliquam ultrices semper. Suspendisse est orci, viverra eget ipsum et, ultricies bibendum nunc.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```css
.diagonal-shadow::before, .diagonal-shadow::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  pointer-events: none;
}
.diagonal-shadow::before, .diagonal-shadow::after {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35%;
  background: inherit;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.diagonal-shadow::before {
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg) scale(1.1);
}
.col{
  padding: 90px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="diagonal-shadow">
<div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum a viverra quam. Vestibulum maximus consequat porta. Duis aliquam ultrices semper. Suspendisse est orci, viverra eget ipsum et, ultricies bibendum nunc.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i added your css code but still not working. can you check under development website   http://173.247.240.143/~metroc14/

Comment: can you please check for me whats going wrong with above css